# Can't access my phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Recently I have set a password for my MySQL database through MySQL console.

After that, I can't access my PHPMyAdmin page. I can't even get to the login screen! Showing this error:

[image: This message came when I tried to access]

How do I fix this?

Comment: PHPMyAdmin seems to be set up to use the root user, so update the config to contain the root users password to allow it to connect.

Comment: check your config.inc.php file and check if the $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie'; and then check the username and pass if there is root and empty password and also the $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

Comment: Just tell me the way How can I reset my password and come back my  previous position, there password was blank and user equal root. @JimL

Comment: just replace the  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config'; withe  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie'; and you will get the login page

Comment: Thank you so much @Rmidi Ayoub

Comment: if my comment was helpful , please could you up vote it . Thanks by advance @ShuvroJyoti

Comment: I tried to vote u but I didn't find the way . Just tell me the process @RmidiAyoub

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just replace the `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';` with `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';` and then you will get the login page where you can put the username and password setted in the conf.inc.php file

Comment: Just one note, I think you mean `config.inc.php` instead of `conf.inc.php`

Comment: @IsaacBennetch yes you're right i.t's already mentioned in my comment ahead